# R: Easier way to make a long data frame with 4 variables?

Tags: r

*edit: I'm trying to do as much of the work on organizing/manipulating the data in R as possible, as a way to practice the basics. Is it a waste of time?*

I have 4 variables: year (2015-2100 every 5 years), country (US, UK), population, and water per capita. 18 Observations for each country so 36 observations total.

What's worked for me so far with ggplot2 is making a long data frame (4x36), mainly by pasting data from excel.

[image: Here's a small example of what I mean]

My end goal is to plot something like this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = years, y = WPC)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(size=population, col = country))
```

- Column 1: 2015-2100 every 5 years, doubled back to back (36 total)
- Column 2: Country names: US 18 times and then UK 18 times
- Column 3: US's population (18) and then UK's population (18)
- Column 4: US's water per capita (18) and then UK's population (18)

I've been making those 4 columns in excel, using `read.delim("clipboard")` to make carry them over to R, one column at a time (I always have to include the column label as the first copied cell because the function automatically turns that cell into the label in R), and then using `data.frame` to combine them into the 4 column data frame.

Is there a better way to combine the vectors in R? I tried simply doing `new.vector <- c(vector1,vector2)` it doesn't combine the values back to back (possibly because they have different column labels?). Someone suggested `c(matrix(a,b), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)` but that made a 2 column list??

So...I guess my two questions are:

1. How do I combine vectors back to back in a single column?
2. Is there a better (not super complicated) way to import small data sets that isn't stupid (copying and using a paste function) or tedious (formatting the data first in excel every time I want to mess with a small data set)?

Comment: Why not just use a package that reads Excel sheets directly into R, such as `readxl` ?

Comment: Would be more sensible to simply save the excel sheet as either tab-delimited or comma-separated values, and then read the file with `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do as much of the work on organizing/manipulating the data in R as possible, as a way to practice the basics. Is it a waste of time?

Comment: Your question makes it seem like your data is already in the correct long format in Excel. If it's in a different format and you want to convert it into long format in R, then you need to show us the not-long format it starts in.

Comment: Keep your Excel and save a copy as `.csv`. Import your data with `read.csv()` and work with that.

Comment: I just wanted to answer the question of doing the data manipulation in R.  It is definitely *not* a waste of time, and in the long run is much more powerful than Excel for this kind of work.